Linear regression predicts probability <0 and >0
I am looking at the relationship between the frequency per thousand population of an event (developing a long term illness) and the probability their income will drop. I expect that if this event is occurring more frequently, the probability of an income drop will also increase. I have calculated a linear regression between a variable which represents the frequency of an event per thousand people and a probability (not just 0 and 1), but in the input of course P is never greater than 1 or less than 0. I got the equation:
P = 0.1 x frequency - 0.05
And so when I get a set of values for frequency, I can use them to calculate P. But for high frequencies per thousand, P can be above 1, or below 0 for low frequencies. I read about log odds being used in this context, which I thought was done by taking the values of P from my regression equation outputs and calculating ln(P/1-P). But because P wasn't between 0 and 1 to start with, P/1-P can still be negative, which would just give an undefined log.
So the probability of this event is a good predictor in the range of my input data, but at some point it breaks. A linear equation is also not really ideal for a probability, it should be harder to get extreme values than it is with this distribution, and it allows you to get probabilities outside 0-1. Is log odds the right tool for this situation, or is a linear regression a bad choice to start with?

An odds ratio applies strictly to probabilities, which by definition lie between 0 and 1.  Your relative frequencies are really just ratios.  They are not probabilities.  Your use of the term "P values" appears to vary and to differ from the conventional meaning.  So, all we really know at this point is that you want to study a ratio in a regression context.  That's not much to go on.  Consider telling us more about your problem and what you're doing, so we will have some information to help you out.

So on one axis I have a frequency per thousand population, that's not a probability. But I'm doing a linear regression between that and a set of probabilities, which are between 0 and 1 in my input data. But if I then use the regression to extrapolate I can get values above and below 1 in my output, maybe because my input never has data extreme enough for this probability to be 1 or 0.
Analogous to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQNRzHKjFw0 but my probability is not just 0 and 1 in the input.

Please search our site for "logistic regression."

When you say "I read about log odds being used in this context" what do you mean by "context"?  What are you trying to do? Because you can't take log odds here.

I came across a site suggesting that the odds ratio is a step towards fixing problems with the range - the youtube link in my comment above also mentions this, with an example that links binomial probability of sale to price of the car. High prices can also push the binomial probability above 1 there when inputting prices into the regression equation, but I didn't understand why the odds ratio fixes this - seems the answer might be 'it doesn't'!

@PeterFlom so what I picked up (maybe incorrectly) was that if I try to predict a probability from linear regression I should symmetrise the distribution and fix the dodgy value ranges. When you say I can't take log odds here, that's because of the negative values or because I can't go from linear regression to logistic regression in the way I described in the question?

There are no problems with the range, there are problems with your thought that what you should do here is logistic regression.  As @whuber said, you haven't got probabilities.

You appear to have ratios as well as something you refer to as "probabilities," but I still can't tell which you are treating as an explanatory variable and which as the response variable.  Logistic regression estimates probabilities based on occurrence data and could be appropriate where your "probabilities" are the response variable; but then all references to the distribution of the explanatory variable (the ratios) make little sense.  Could you edit your post to clarify what your data are and what you want to accomplish?

If your outcome is a frequency, not binary, you can still apply logistic regression, but as a quasi-model, using quasi-likelihood it is called fractional response regression  see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530149/help-with-needed-with-fractional-outcomes-logit-regression

@whuber I've added to it - I expect that if this event is occurring more frequently then the probability of an income drop will also increase. I get very good R^2 over the range of the input data, but when I extend the range of the ratio it can push P above 1. Also for probabilities the log odds distribution is better at capturing the need for very high and very low probabilities to require larger changes in frequency, but perhaps this just means linear regression is a bad idea to start with. Thanks for your comments and patience, they have helped me to expand and improve on the questions :)

@PeterFlom Apologies, this was poor question writing on my part, I have explicitly given the variables I am using - I am looking at the relationship between the frequency per thousand population of an event (developing a long term illness) and the probability their income will drop.

This sounds like a standard logistic regression.  The data are ordered pairs (frequency, y) where y=1 indicates a drop in income and y=0 indicates otherwise.  Post-hoc goodness of fit tests will indicate whether (and to some extent how) to deal with special behavior at the extremes (one can use splines and/or transformation of the frequency values).
